# Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate - creates a random string in the URL

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

Every time I create a .NET 4 Webforms (c#) site and just hit F5 I always get a URL string like this:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx:1086/(S(np4ocj1z5ze4ziohswu1zde4))/default.aspx
```

As I test I just tried to publish a new site with nothing done to it and it also uses a random string in the URL when I put the site on IIS.

Is there a way of turning this off as image locations are becoming a problem?

Comment: It looks like you're storing your session ID in the URI. Have you enabled cookieless sessions in your web.config file?

Comment: Thanks Dai = it was cookieless sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(My comment to the Question was right, so I'm adding this as an answer for sweet, sweet karma).

It looks like you're storing your session ID in the URI. Have you enabled cookieless sessions in your web.config file?